# specifying highlight fields at runtime in elasticsearch Nest library

Tags: nest, elasticsearch-net

in NEST library of ElasticSearch for NET, we can highlight on somefields.staticly we can determine highlightin fields in code. but in this case we cannot specify highligh terms at Runtime to allow user to select highlighting fields.

How can i specify highlighting fields at runtime?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you think about .OnField("fieldName")?

Comment: i want to user select the highlighting fields.

Comment: `.On.Field(fieldSelectedByUser)`? Where `fieldSelectedByUser` variable with value from input or dropdown.